# Distributing Items Evenly Across a Number of Days

Tags: c#, algorithm, distribution

I need to distribute a remainder of items over a fixed number of days. e.g. say I have 197 items and 75 days to distribute them over. If I display 2 items for 75 days then I have 47 items not displayed. How do I distribute the remaining 47 items over the 75 days evenly so that I will get a sequence like 2,3,3,2,3,3,2,2,3.... i.e. the 3's are evenly distributed over the whole display. This is what I have so far

```
const double num = (double)197/75;
double temp = num;
var list = new List<int>();
for (var t = 1; t <= days; t++)
{
    var intPart = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(temp).ToString());

    list.Add(intPart);

    var remainder = num - intPart;

    temp = num + remainder;
}
```

but I only end up with 187 items displayed. I'm missing 10.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How about converting to seconds, say?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. When I say evenly I mean that I would only want a max of 3 items in any one "bucket". So basically I would like the 47 remaining items to be distributed as evenly as possible over the 75 "buckets" that already have 2 items each in. I thought that by keeping track of the remainder that this would accomplish my goal but I'm thinking now that I may have to do some recalculations as I insert the integers into the list. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original answer that turned out to give suboptimal results in some cases, as noted by AlexD:

```
int numItems = 197;
int numDays = 75;
var list = new List<int>();
for (int t = 0; t < numDays; t++)
{
    int numItemsInDay = ((t+1)*numItems+numDays/2)/numDays - (t*numItems+numDays/2)/numDays;
    list.Add(numItemsInDay);
}
```

The idea is that every item goes into the day defined by the rounded value of `itemIndex*numDays/numItems`, and you can calculate the number of items in a day directly, without keeping track of previous items.

---

Another approach.

To spread `numItems` items among `numDays` days as evenly as possible, you need to group the days into spans of days with `floor(numItems/numDays)` items and spans of days with `ceil(numItems/numDays)` items, spreading *the spans* as evenly as possible. So the problem can be solved by recursively reducing the number of days to the number of spans.

```
static List<int> Spread(int numDays, int numItems)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    if (numDays <= 1)
    {
        if (numDays == 1)
            result.Add(numItems);
        return result;
    }
    int numItemsInDayLower = numItems/numDays;
    int numItemsInDayHigher = numItemsInDayLower+1;
    int numDaysHigher = numItems - numItemsInDayLower * numDays;
    int numDaysLower = numDays-numDaysHigher;
    int numSpansLower = numDaysLower > numDaysHigher ? numDaysHigher + 1 : numDaysLower;
    int numSpansHigher = numDaysHigher > numDaysLower ? numDaysLower + 1 : numDaysHigher;
    bool isStartingFromSpanLower = numDaysLower > numDaysHigher;
    List<int> spanLehgthsLower = Spread(numSpansLower, numDaysLower);
    List<int> spanLehgthsHigher = Spread(numSpansHigher, numDaysHigher);
    for (int iSpan = 0; iSpan < spanLehgthsLower.Count + spanLehgthsHigher.Count; iSpan++)
    {
        if ((iSpan % 2 == 0) == isStartingFromSpanLower)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < spanLehgthsLower[iSpan/2]; i++)
                result.Add(numItemsInDayLower);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < spanLehgthsHigher[iSpan/2]; i++)
                result.Add(numItemsInDayHigher);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @AlexD Mathematically speaking yes, but because of the truncation which occurs when dividing integers, it is not. 

+1 for a very good solution, just a small suggestion, consider using an array and setting the items rather than adding to a list; you know in advance how many items there will be.

Comment: @Lukazoid Definitely a good idea, but e.g. for days=5 items=3 we get `01011`, while in ideal case is should be perhaps `10101`.

Comment: @AlexD Good point. It should be the rounded value, not floor; I fixed the answer. Now for 5 days it yields `00100`, `01010`, `10101`, `11011`, `11111`, `11211`, `12121`, and so on.

Comment: Good! I'm afraid to become boring, but now for `6` items, `8` days we get `11011101` instead of `11011011`. (Well, we do not have a formal definition for "*evenly*", but intuitively I would expect `11011011`.)

Comment: @AlexD You're right, and that one doesn't seem to be fixable. It also puts two items at approximately 1/4 and 3/4 of the interval, rather than 1/3 and 2/3. So I came up with a completely different algorithm.

Comment: Yep, looks elegant, +1. A small remark: could it be that `numDaysLower == numDaysHigher ? numDaysHigher : numDaysLower` always evaluates to `numDaysLower` :)?

Comment: @AlexD Oh, right. Fixed that too. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you have really helped me out.